# Get unique rows from a cross reference table where all items reference each other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a cross reference table of part numbers (PN).  There are 2 columns, PN and ALT_PN.  All part numbers cross reference each other.

I need to create a report showing only the unique values in this table.  Example, only show that A has alternate of B, and not show that B is an alternate of A.

I found solutions for Mysql that work, but they don't work in Oracle 11g.

```
Create table temp ( id integer primary key, PN varchar(10), Alt_PN 
varchar(10));

insert into temp values(1,'A','B');
insert into temp values(2,'B','A');
insert into temp values(3,'X','Y');
insert into temp values(4,'Y','X');
insert into temp values(5,'C','D');
insert into temp values(6,'C','E');
insert into temp values(7,'D','C');
insert into temp values(8,'D','E');
insert into temp values(9,'E','C');
insert into temp values(10,'E','D');
```

i only want to return IDs of 1, 3, 5, 6 and 8

Comment: What about `select * from temp where pn < alt_pn`?

Comment: The part numbers in the example are just for simplicity, they are actually long alpha numeric with hypens, etc.. there is no alphabetical relationship between them.,

Comment: Still, the `<` operator will filter out *reverse* `VARCHAR2` duplicates.

Comment: Why not id = 8?

Comment: @The Impaler- you were correct, this does return the correct result even with alphanumerics..

Comment: @forpas.. yes correct, i updated the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all cross reference each other, just do:

```
select t.*
from temp t
where t.pn < t.alt_pn;
```

This will return one row from each pair, and works on any type.

If you are concerned that not all pairs are present, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by least(t.pn, t.alt_pn), least(t.pn, t.alt_pn) order by t.pn) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```